# C# - Access XML attributes

Tags: c#, xml

I want to access an attribute `type` where the value of `abc` is `female`

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\Employees.xml");
var name = from nm in xelement.Elements("Employee")
            where (string)nm.(Element("Abc") == "Female").Attribute("Type") == "Att"
            select nm;
```

This didn't work. Any way to make it happen?

Comment: This didn't work.. Means ????? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @MicrosoftDJ: He's getting a very large number of compiler errors from his totally non-sensical code.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you also posted the xml ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work. It would be useful to see the Xml though.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\test.xml");
var result = doc.Descendants("Employee")
                .Where(x=>(string)x.Value== "female")
                .Select(x=>x.Attribute("type").Value);
```

This is assuming the xml is something like this, the query would return "foo1".

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>-
   <Employee type="foo">
      <abc>male</abc>
   </Employee>
   <Employee type="foo1">
      <abc>female</abc>
   </Employee>
   <Employee type="foo2">
      <abc>male</abc>
   </Employee>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make any sense.

You cannot nest comparisons and casts and objects like that.

Instead, you need to use the `&&` operator to check each condition separately.

Answer (score 0):

## Use XMLReader

More information from MSDN:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx

Comment: LINQ to XML is _much_ easier to use than XmlReader.